# migrate form my sql to postgres then keep updating

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-migration, pgloader

right now am using pgloader to migrate a MySQL database to a PostgreSQL DB.

The migration working fine but the issue that I want to update my Postgres DB after the migration from MySQL, is that possible?

right now every time I migrate it delete the previous data then create it again with the latest data from MySQL.

Comment: Maybe something like https://debezium.io/ or https://pgchameleon.org/ ?

Comment: The [mysql_fdw](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw)?